# Is the "Short" data type available in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I came across this document listing the various data types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/index

I wrote in a "short" variable, but received the following error upon debugging: "User-defined type not defined". Is "short" an available data type in VBA?

```
Dim CalcState As short

CalcState = Application.Calculation
```

Comment: That is the VB.Net documentation. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) is the VBA documentation.

Comment: VBA is not part of the dot net platform - it predates it by a number of years...    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/visual-basic-language-reference

Comment: Just use a `Long`. VBA does have an `Integer` type but there is no benefit in using it.

Comment: Thanks, BigBen. That's the list I needed.

Also thanks for the other responses. Helps to know the background and differences between the systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`short` is a language alias for `System.Int16`.

The 16-bit integer type in VBA is `Integer`.

For reference, the 32-bit integer type is `Long`, and in VBA7 x64 there's a 64-bit integer type too, `LongLong`.

That said there isn't really any need to use a 16-bit integer. Just use a `Long` unless you're *required* to use something else (say, because you're invoking some legacy API).